# Access to class scope inside lambda in TypeScript is undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, scope, this

I have the following class in TypeScript that is used as a Pipe by Angular 2 to render markdown. It compiles without errors, but hits an exception at runtime on the marked line:

```
var Remarkable = require('remarkable');

@Pipe({
    name: 'markdown'
})
export class MarkdownPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public remarkable;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
        this.remarkable = new Remarkable({
            typographer: true
        });

        this.remarkable.use(this.parseVideos);
    }

    transform(value: string) : SafeHtml {
        if (value != null) {
            return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.remarkable.render(value));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public parseVideos(md) : void {
        md.inline.ruler.push('video', (state) => {
            return this.parseMedia(state, '@', 'video'); // this is undefined
        });
    }

    public parseMedia(state, startingMarker, tokenName) : boolean {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

When I this code attempts to execute, I get a runtime error telling me that:

[image]

Where `_this` refers to the same line I have commented above. Why is this? My IDE reports that I should have access to the `parseMedia` method inside of my lambda expression.

[image]

What's the best solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you pass it here:

```
this.remarkable.use(this.parseVideos);
```

Then when the method is invoked the `this` no longer points to your instance of `MarkdownPipe`.

In order to preserve the right scope for `this` you can either have another arrow function:

```
this.remarkable.use(md => this.parseVideos(md));
```

Or you can use the [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
this.remarkable.use(this.parseVideos.bind(this));
```

Comment: Right. I expected it to be something like this. Thanks. My IDE autocomplete threw me off.

Comment: so is there any case where you can pass in a closure/lambda directly?

Comment: @stt106 I'm not sure what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: I mean whats in the OP is wrong in this case, is there any case the way used in OP is correct?

Comment: @stt106 If the passed in function doesn't require the use of `this`, then there's no problem with passing it without it being bound. Another option is to have a bound method, for example, to do this in the ctor: `this.parseVideos = this.parseVideos.bind(this);`

Comment: Now I know why my IDE was suggesting me to to use this notation for function ` () => {} ` . Which i ignored for too long.